# Rotating an image without external function

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, image-processing, scipy

I have an image which I read using `scipy.misc.imread`.

The pivot (`[0,0]`) is in the top left side of the image.
I want to flip it by 90 degrees clockwise.

The result I got was:

[image]

I hope you can find the mistake and how do I fix it:

1. For point `(x,y)` and image size `h=Image_Hieght-1` and `w=Image_Width-1`, I changed the pivot to be at the center of the graph. `(x,y) -> (x-w/2,y-h/2)`.
2. Now I can use the linear transformation of rotating a point in 90 degrees clockwise:

   - `(1,0) -> (0,-1)`
   - `(0,-1) -> (1,0)`
   - Conclustion: `(x1,y1) -> (y1,-x1)` ==> `(x - w/2,y - h/2) -> (y-h/2,w/2 - x)`
3. Now, I need to move back the point to the original graph (before I did `(x,y) -> (x-w/2,y-h/2)`): `(y-h/2,w/2 - x) -> (y-h/2+h/2,w/2 - x+w/2) = (y,w-x)`

   - In the code I'm using `i,j` (`i` = row, `j`= column), so `(y,w-x) == (-j+w,i)`

Conclustion:

```
def movePointBy90(hieght, width, i, j):
    iNew = -j + width - 1
    jNew = i
    return int(iNew), int(jNew)
```

The rest of the code:

```
image1 = imread('image.jpg')
image2 = np.zeros([image1.shape[1], image1.shape[0], image1.shape[2]])
print(image1.shape)
print(image2.shape)
for c in range(2):
    for i in range(image1.shape[0]-1):
        for j in range(image1.shape[1]-1):
            newPoint = moveBy90(image1.shape[0], image1.shape[1], i, j)
            image2[newPoint[0], newPoint[1], c]=image1[i,j,c]


plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.imshow(image1)

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.imshow(image2)
plt.show()
```

---

#### Update:

After changing to (I thought the `range` is a close range):

```
for c in range(3):
    for i in range(image1.shape[0]):
        for j in range(image1.shape[1]):
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>How many channels your image have? When I change range of c variable in for loop it works correctly. From</s>

```
for c in range(2):
```

I think that is an issue of numpy/matplotlib with pixel values of your image. If your intensity values are in range [0,255] instead of [0,1], you should first perform

```
image1 = image1 / 255
```

after reading your image and it will be displayed correctly.

Update: I run code below with your image and got shown result, the important point is to specify the data type of your new initialized array.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def moveBy90(hieght, width, i, j):
    iNew = -j + width - 1
    jNew = i
    return int(iNew), int(jNew)

image1 = plt.imread('3PWin.png')
image2 = np.zeros([image1.shape[1], image1.shape[0], image1.shape[2]], dtype=image1.dtype)
for c in range(4):
    for i in range(image1.shape[0]-1):
        for j in range(image1.shape[1]-1):
            newPoint = moveBy90(image1.shape[0], image1.shape[1], i, j)
            try:
                image2[newPoint[0], newPoint[1], c]=image1[i,j,c]
            except IndexError as error:
                print(error)

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.imshow(image1)

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.imshow(image2)
plt.show()
```

[image: result of your example image]

Comment: the image is `RGB` so `c` can be zero,one or 2.

Comment: How is it working? After changing to `4`, II only see white and yellow in the picture.

Comment: Updated my answer, at first I got correct answer because I tried my own png image.

Comment: Thanks for updating. I put your code before any of my code and I got IndexError. But, most importantly, why does it matter that I will work in the range of `[0,1]`?

Comment: As specified in the [matplotlib document](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html)  if your image data type is float, your pixel values must be in range [0, 1], and [0, 255] for integers. You can see the type via image1.dtype.

Comment: My inage type is int.

Comment: I uploaded my obtained result.

Comment: lol nice picture ;) Thank you! Can you specify what was the problem?

Comment: I think I found the actual source of problem. You should specify data type for your initialized array. Change
`image2 = np.zeros([image1.shape[1], image1.shape[0], image1.shape[2]])`
to
`image2 = np.zeros([image1.shape[1], image1.shape[0], image1.shape[2]], dtype=image1.dtype)`
Also at first, your channel count was wrong too.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure to rotate an image seems rather complicated. Just using `numpy` means you may rotate 3 times by 90 degrees to achieve the equivalent of a 90 degrees clockwise rotation

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import misc

data_orig = misc.face()
data_rotated = np.rot90(data_orig, k=3)

plt.imshow(data_rotated)

plt.show()
```

Or, if you want to use scipy,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import misc
from scipy.ndimage import rotate

data_orig = misc.face()  # or use data_orig = imread('image.jpg')
data_rotated = rotate(data_orig, 270)

plt.imshow(data_rotated)

plt.show()
```

In both cases the image is rotated 90° clockwise:

[image]

Comment: Or you use the `k` argument to `rot90` and rotate by 270 degrees in a single step: `np.rot90(data_orig, 3)`!

Comment: Thanks, @CrisLuengo that is of course much simpler.